# Are there any known issues with Open Graph and IE9 that involve XSLT pages?

Tags: xslt, internet-explorer-9, facebook-opengraph

I'm looking into a problem that involves Sharing News stories. I'm not sure how much specific info I'm allowed to give since this is for a larger company.  We manage several websites for various news papers all over Canada. I've been tasked with figuring out what the source of the problem here is, and I'm stumped...

When you share a story from one of our sites, like http://www.richmond-news.com/Elderly+robbed+broad+daylight/6814513/story.html

The share button takes you to Facebook, as expected. It then displays the thumbnail, headline, etc., on that page.

However, for that site (and several other ones) if you try that in Internet Explorer 9, the thumbnail will not load.

The news pages have XSLT templates that generate all of the data that Facebook needs to generate this sharing link.

Since there isn't a whole lot of room for error here, my best guess is that it may be an IE9 thing. So my question is, are there any known issues with Facebook Open Graph, IE9 and XLST working in tandem?

Comment: Where are you using XSLT – on the server side or the client side? If you’re using it server-side (I couldn’t see anything client-side), then this should not factor in in any way – any client, be it Facebook’s scraper or an IE 9, should not see any of that XSLT and they should get the same HTML output. And when sharing a link, the browser itself should not have much to do which the page itself either, it’s Facebook’s script that does mostly all the work there.

Comment: [Cont.] I could only imagine that it’s a problem with loading the image itself (don’t know if FB serves it from their own servers in preview, or if they just make the browser fetch the original URL). Try using IE9’s debug tools ([F12]) to see what requests are being made while using the share dialog, and if the request for the image get’s answered in an “unusual” way (500, 404, 403, …)

Comment: Thanks CBroe. The XSLT is server side.  I tried using the IE9 debug tool, but to no avail. It revealed no issues to me, and everything seemed to be handled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating further:  Some stories on a domain will show a thumbnail for the article in question and others will not.

I also discovered that other websites (ones that we do not own or maintain) will also do this. It seems like its a bug with IE9 and Facebook Open Graph.